# Why are up-votes free?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, voting, upvotes

If down-votes cost rep to make the user think before giving a well-deserved down-vote, why can I give out up-votes like hot cakes with no consequence?

Comment: Hot cakes are delicious. Especially Chocolate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only down votes on answers cost reputation, you can down vote questions for free.

If I'm not mistaken, the reason down voting answers costs rep is to discourage answerers from down voting competing answers to try to game the system for more up votes.

So I guess up votes are free because a major issue with free up votes has not been identified, where making them cost rep is a possible solution.

Comment: I wasn't around to see it happen, but I remember reading that in SO's early days upvotes weren't rate-limited until someone wrote a bot that upvoted everything.  But there doesn't seem to be a need for further restrictions.

Comment: I see, so essentially because no one is complaining about free up-votes.